# lazy load of images issues for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am working on lazy load of images for UICollectionView. The Image are showing but when I scroll the UICollectionView, images change their positions and there are repetition of images where all the images should be unique. Here is my code:

```
- (gridcell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    gridcell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"gallerycollection" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *appsdict = [array_grid objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    cell.image_grid.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"griddummyloading"];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

        NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[appsdict objectForKey:@"iosthumbnail"]];

        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            cell.image_grid.image=image;
        });
    });

    [collectionview_grid setAllowsSelection:YES];

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Are you removing the image from the cell in the cell's `prepareForReuse` method? If not, it is likely showing the image from the previous use of the cell.

Comment: my code i need to change anything?

Comment: are you using multiple section in uicollectionview?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use a third party library to lazy load images, like [this one](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), which also supports web caching.
Also, consider the conventions used in objective-c:
- avoid snake_casing, use camelCase
- make extensive use of properties
- use upper cased class names

Answer (score -1):

Hey theres a very good example given at Apple developer site.

This [is an example code](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) where apple demonstrates a way of doing lazy loading in a table.. referring to this might  help you out in some way.
All the best